# first come first serve php

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in php and working on a webservice to increase itemQuantity from iphone end. When the user hits the + button to increase quantity of an item multiple times , then it some times does not accurately increase the quantity. iphone is sending me increased quantity everytime. I mean 26 then 27 then 28.

But when I tried to debugged it I found some time it firstly serve the database with 28 then update it to 27 . can anybody please help ? function I am using is as following....

```
function update_query($tblName,$queryArr,$condition)
{
if(!empty($this->_database)){
if(!mysql_select_db($this->_database, $this->_link) ) 
{
 $this->_errorstr = "Couldn't change database: ".$this->_database."
 My-SQL     Error ".mysql_error($this->_link);
 }
 }
 $fields=@array_keys($queryArr);
 $values=@array_values($queryArr);
 $update="";
 for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++)
 {
$update.="$fields[$i]='".addslashes($values[$i])."',";
 }
 $update=substr($update,0,-1);
  $query="update $tblName set $update $condition";
//  echo $query


   //echo  $query."<br>";
 //die;
  $this->_errorstr = "";
  $this->_query = $query;
  $this->_result = mysql_query( $this->_query, $this->_link );
  if ( ! $this->_result )
  {
    $this->_errorstr = "Error : ".mysql_error( $this->_link );
    $this->_success = false;
  }
 else
 {
   $this->_success = true;

}
return $this->_success;
 }
```

Comment: Remove those `@` symbols, you might see the errors...

Comment: Are your request arriving in correct order from the iphone?

Comment: Are you having it send a request every time the user hits the increase quantity button on their phone?

Comment: You need to provide much more information.  See the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You mean when a customer increases quantity of an item, the sever has to deal with the changes all the way up? How wasteful of both bandwidth and CPU.

Comment: Yes Jprofitt...I am getting request every time user hits the increase quantity button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if two requests arrive at the same time to your application and both read the same value from the db?

Use `SET quantity = quantity + 1` in you mysql query instead.

This does not solve the display problem in your iphone application, but at least, the users command has been stored inside the data.

To solve the display problem, you need to change the design of your application. For example, increase on client side and store later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot hakre.. Answering to your question "What happens if two requests arrive at .... ?" , It stores 27 instead of 28 in the database..It firstly save 28 in datbase and then update it with 27....